# How to avoid the last newline in sed?

Tags: sed

I want to remove the last part of a file, starting at a line following a certain pattern *and including the preceding newline*.

So, stopping at "STOP", the following file:

```
keep\n
STOP\n
whatever
```

Should output:

```
keep
```

With no trailing newline.

I tried this, and the logic seems to work, but it seems that sed adds a newline every time it prints its buffer. How can I avoid that? When sed doesn't manipulate the buffer, I don't have that problem (IE If I remove the STOP, sed outputs 'whatever' at the end of the file without a newline).

```
printf 'keep
STOP
Whatever' | sed 'N
/\nSTOP/ {
  s/\n.*$//
  P
  Q
}
P
D'
```

I'm trying to write a git cleaning filter, and I cannot have a new newline appended every time I commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^STOP/{exit} {printf "%s%s", ors, $0; ors=RS}' file
keep$
```

The above prints every line without a trailing newline but **preceded** by a newline (`\n` or `\r\n` - whichever your environment dictates so it'll behave correctly on UNIX or Windows or whatever) for every 2nd and subsequent line. When it finds a STOP line it just exits before printing anything.

Note that the above doesn't keep anything in memory except the current line so it'll work no matter how large your input file is and no matter where the STOP appears in it - it'll even work if STOP is the first line of the file unlike the other answers you have so far.

It will also work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Comment: Oh yeah, pretty neat.

Comment: Oooh, is it that ors, being lowercase, is a variable, hence empty until the assignment at the end of the first loop?

Comment: yes it is. It's one of the pretty common approaches to printing something for the 2nd and subsequent lines.

Comment: I must admit  like it a lot. OK, I'll keep using the sed solution, because it fits better in my situation, but I'm marking this one as an answer because it can benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\nSTOP.*//' file
```

The `-z` option slurps the whole file into memory and the substitute command, removes the remainder of the file from the first newline followed by `STOP`.

Comment: Holly Molly, it works. I use git on Windows, so it includes Cygwin, and Cygwin uses the GNU version of utilities. That's almost too simple after all my trials and errors. Short of an explanation of the internals of sed, that's the answer I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @XavierPlantefève you do understand though that it'll fail when you move to another platform that doesn't have GNU sed, and it'll fail if you have a file that's huge since it reads the whole file into memory at one time and it'll be much slower than the awk scripts posted. You can write almost exactly the same script in GNU awk (`awk -v RS='^$' '{sub(/\nSTOP.*/,"")}1'`) but you wouldn't because there's more robust, portable, efficient ways of doing the job.

Comment: I perfectly understand, but in this case, the test bed is very controlled: it's for a git filter on Windows, that will never receive more than maybe a couple hundred lines at most. The scope is purely Windows, because of service structure. More than that, the easier it is to understand for future admins, the better it is. That and the fact that the question was about sed made me choose this answer. Be assured I bookmarked your answer for personal growth and for reference in future projects, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you could:

```
$ awk '$0=="STOP"{exit} {b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0} END{printf "%s",b}' file
```

Output:

```
keep$
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '                        
    $0=="STOP" { exit }        # exit at STOP, ie. go to END
    { b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0 }  # gather an output buffer, control \n
    END { printf "%s",b }      # in the END output output buffer
' file
```

... more (focusing a bit on the *conditional operator*):

```
    b=b             # appending to b, so b is b and ...
    (b==""?"":ORS)  # if b was empty, add nothing to it, if not add ORS ie. \n ...
    $0              # and the current record
```

Comment: Aww man, I just spent a day learning sed multiline syntax and now I've got to learn awk? :D

Can you further break down the second line? I get that b is a variable here, the so-called buffer, I read that ORS is the new line, I understand that $0 is the current line in the pipe and that == is a test. But I fail to put those elements together here... (I'm a Windows PowerShell guy.)

Comment: Isn't life wonderful, learn more every day? :D I'll try to clarify the line in a sec.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. If ever someone pass by searching for a sed replacement, I'll just add that the first condition can be replaced by a regexp this way:  $0~'STOP.*'

Comment: @XavierPlantefève sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk for portability, clarity, robustness, efficiency and everything else that matters in software. All the sed constructs to do anything else literally became obsolete about 40 years ago when awk was invented and still exist today just for the mental exercise - you don't actually use them in production software.